# Healthvault_putting data

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to add a new wEIGHT value to healthvault
When I used the code provided with SDK its wrkng fine
I splitted the code to use with another UI.Now its giving me errors
Logcat is showng No errors.
Error message is "An exception occured:null"

This is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.customlist.R;
import com.microsoft.hsg.Request;
import com.microsoft.hsg.android.HealthVaultService;


import com.microsoft.hsg.android.demo.hv.Weight;
import com.microsoft.hsg.request.SimpleRequestTemplate;

 public class AddWeight extends Activity {

private HealthVaultService service;
//    private Record selectedRecord;
String recd_id = "";
String persn_id = "";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addweight);
    service = HealthVaultService.getInstance();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    recd_id  = intent.getExtras().getString("recd_id");
    persn_id  = intent.getExtras().getString("persn_id");
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_wght);
            PutWeight putAction = new PutWeight(text.getText().toString());
            putAction.execute();
        }
    });


    Button backpage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    backpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            service.reset();
            Intent i = new Intent(AddWeight.this,WeightActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
   });


}



private class PutWeight extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String weight;
    private Exception exception;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public PutWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                AddWeight.this,
                "",
                "Saving Data",
                true);
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        try {

            putWeight(weight);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            exception = e;
        }

        return null;
     }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (exception == null) {
          Intent i=new Intent(AddWeight.this,WeightActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                AddWeight.this,
                "An error occurred.  " + exception.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }   
}
private void putWeight(String value)
{
    Weight weight = new Weight(Double.parseDouble(value));

    SimpleRequestTemplate template = new SimpleRequestTemplate(
            service.getConnection(),
           persn_id,
            recd_id);

    StringBuilder infoBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    infoBuilder.append("<info><thing><type-id>");
    infoBuilder.append(Weight.TYPE);
    infoBuilder.append("</type-id><data-xml>");
    infoBuilder.append(weight.toXml());
    infoBuilder.append("<common/></data-xml></thing></info>");

    Request request = new Request();
    request.setMethodName("PutThings");
    request.setInfo(infoBuilder.toString());
    template.makeRequest(request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding `AsyncTask` constructor and not calling `super()`.
Anyway is there any purpose in doing this? You can start showing dialog in `onPreExecute()` method, and pass your `weight` variable to `execute` method. Just tweak your `AsyncTask` so that `doInBackground` can take params, and call it like `new PutWeight().execute(text.getText().toString())`